# How to set Task Decorator in Task Executor through XML configuration?

Tags: spring, logging, spring-integration, decorator, mdc

I have an application that uses Spring Integration for Parallel calls. All configurations are in the config.xml. Is there a way to set the decorator of every task executor I placed but still using the XML configuration?
I have to pass the MDC from the main thread to the parallel threads of my logger.

```
<task:executor id="taskExecutor" pool-size="650-700"
               queue-capacity="3000" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>
```

This is the task executor config I have right now.

Answer (score 2):

It can't be specified with `<task:executor/>` as it is not supported. Rather you can define a separate bean like this and configure your own task decorator

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="4" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="4" />
    <property name="WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
    <property name="taskDecorator" ref="taskDecorator" />
</bean>
```